# Other's can't connect to my Minecraft Server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hosting

I created a Minecraft server for my sister and I, and we're using the same connection, but she can't seem to connect to the server where as I can, and we're only 10 meters apart and both using wired connectivity. And something that struck me odd was the fact that my Ipv4 address did not start with "192.168" rather "10.0".

I gave her my Ipv4 to connect and it just says it's unable to connect to the server, everything on my end is fine, however.

Comment: Are you using 2 mojang accounts, or is it a pirate version?

Answer (score 1):

If both computers are on the same subnet (first three octets of the IP address are the same on both computers), likely the reason, assuming you are on Windows would be the Windows Firewall. You have to disable it or punch a hole in it for the Minecraft connection. If you are on Linux, then iptables/firewalld may be blocking it for the same reason.

In theory it shouldn't matter if the subnets are different if you enter a complete IP address to connect to in Minecraft, but if they were different, I'd be curious what is going on with your home network that you have multiple discreet private networks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the Wi-Fi I have at home to play LAN games. But if you have a smart-phone, you could use the Personal Hotspot to play a LAN world at home. Make sure the account is not a pirated version.